# "ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask" but the version is right there

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to setup an environment for Machine Learning in Visual Studio Code.

The problem I'm facing is:

```
$ pip install Flask==**0.9**
Collecting Flask==0.9
  Using cached Flask-0.9.tar.gz (481 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: '<hidden-path>' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\davidson.lima\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t35zbwu_\\flask_f8c103077d3d4f02ba49d3dfb4ffd4c1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\davidson.lima\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t35zbwu_\\flask_f8c103077d3d4f02ba49d3dfb4ffd4c1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\davidson.lima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-6ph75l9f'
         cwd: C:\Users\davidson.lima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t35zbwu_\flask_f8c103077d3d4f02ba49d3dfb4ffd4c1\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\davidson.lima\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t35zbwu_\flask_f8c103077d3d4f02ba49d3dfb4ffd4c1\setup.py", line 62     
        print "Audit requires PyFlakes installed in your system."
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Audit requires PyFlakes installed in your system.")?        
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/0a/fe5021b35436202d3d4225a766f3bdc7fb51521ad89e73c5162db36cdbc7/Flask-0.9.tar.gz#sha256=2fd5d4ffe81f762dd2a3e58472d690a0dbba3766776506003aee3ed7aaa8afef (from https://pypi.org/simple/flask/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==0.9 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, **0.9**, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.4, 0.12.5, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask==0.9
```

What is making me going crazy is that the version I'm trying to use is 0.9 and it's obviously available in the list, as highlighted above.

Can you help me? I seeked similar questions but all them failed, so it's not duplicated.

Comment: Flask 0.9 was released in 2012, it uses python 2, while you are using python 3. That is why you get an error.

Comment: I can't understand why this question received negative votes. Is it that obvious? The documentation I received for the environment didn't specify the Python version, or at least the requirements.txt should consider different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you installing particularly $ pip install Flask==**0.9**. Its version may don't support your device .just simply install $pip install flask.

Comment: 0.9 is a request from the environment I'm trying to configure.